# Problema al leer un carácter para luego imprimirlo

Tags: c

Actualmente me encuentro aprendiendo C, estoy empezando por lo básico haciendo programas simple para practicar conceptos. Me he encontrado con un problema a la hora de leer un caracter para luego imprimirlo, paso a explicar en detalle.

El siguiente programa utiliza la función cuadrado para imprimir en pantalla un cuadrado con las dimensiones y el carácter especificados por el usuario:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void cuadrado(int lado, char caracter);

int main()
{
  int l;
  char car;

  printf("Inserte un caracter: ");
  scanf("%c", &car);

  printf("Inserte la longitud de lado del cuadrado: ");
  scanf("%d", &l);

  cuadrado(l,car);

  return 0;
}

void cuadrado(int lado, char caracter)
{
  int i, j;

  for (i = 1; i <= lado; i++)
  {
    for (j = 1; j <= lado; j++)
    {
      printf("%c", caracter);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

El programa escrito como lo puse arriba compila y funciona bien dando como salida por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Si cambio el orden de lectura de las variables, es decir primero solicito que se ingrese la longitud del lado y luego el carácter, lo cual seria cambiar:

```
  ...
  printf("Inserte un caracter: ");
  scanf("%c", &car);

  printf("Inserte la longitud de lado del cuadrado: ");
  scanf("%d", &l);
  ...
```

Por

```
  ...   
  printf("Inserte la longitud de lado del cuadrado: ");
  scanf("%d", &l);

  printf("Inserte un caracter: ");
  scanf("%c", &car);
  ...
```

Compila bien como es de esperar pero a la hora de la ejecución pasa lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No estoy seguro de cual es problema, lo que yo interpreto es que toma un carácter en blanco como entrada, pero no se si así realmente y tampoco se como solucionarlo sin cambiar el orden de las instrucciones de lectura.

Agradecería si alguien me puede aclarar cual es el problema o si estoy haciendo algo mal. En este programa en concreto ya lo pude solucionar invirtiendo el orden de las instrucciones de lectura como aclare arriba, pero de todos modo me gustaría saber que esta mal para evitar futuros errores.

Comment: Leí tu respuesta pero no estoy seguro si entendi, scanf estaría leyendo el carácter como vació cuando yo pulso ENTER para confirmar la lectura del entero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El funcionamiento de `scanf( )` **no es igual** en todos los casos. En el código de ejemplo, las acciones son las siguientes:

1. `%c` -> lee **1** solo caracter. **Deja** el `\n` en el *buffer*.
2. `%d` -> **ignora los separadores** hasta que encuentra un número. Recoge ese número. Deja el `\n` en el *buffer*.

Al cambiar tu código, se invierten los pasos.

1. `%d` -> **ignora los separadores** hasta que encuentra un número. Recoge ese número. Deja el `\n` en el *buffer*.
2. `%c` -> lee **1** solo caracter ( el `\n` dejado anteriormente ). Vuelve a dejar un `\n` en el buffer.

Los *separadores* son, entre otros, el  (espacio), `\n` (salto de línea), `\t` (tabulador horizontal), ...

Es decir, al **leer un número**, se **ignoran** todos los posibles `\n` dejados por llamadas anteriores. Al leer un cáracter, el `\n` es considerado un carácter, y no se ignora.

La solución estándar es hacer

```
scanf( ... ); // Leemos lo que necesitemos/queramos.
getc( stdin ); // Eliminamos el \n residual del buffer de entrada.
```

Comment: Perfecto ahora si me quedo claro, muchas gracias